# Bandpass For RC Circuit

Tags: transfer-function

How do I obtain the transfer function for this RC Bandpass Filter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJlHVp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You just entered it into a circuit simulator, so simulate it already!

Comment: Dear new user, welcome to EE.SE. People here is more than happy to help you undestand electrical engineering concepts, but only if you show some effort to solve the problem by yourself. We don't like to do your homework for you, but some of us will sure be glad to guide you through it. So, what do you know about transfer functions and RC bandpass filters? Have you googled it?

Comment: I have done this problem so many times on paper but I am not coming up with the right answer. I am in Bioinstrumentation and my professor goes through the problems very quickly! I've been on google all day looking for help but every resource using different notation from what my professor assigned so I am basically lost when it comes to understanding.

Comment: Post what you believe is the right answer as well as the answer you've come up with.  Perhaps they're the same after some algebra.

Comment: O.k but quick question my gain for this circuit should be in volts then I convert it to dB, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If \$V_{R1}\$ is the voltage across \$R_1\$, then, by voltage division, the voltage across \$C_2\$ is

$$V_{out} = V_{C2} = V_{R1}\frac{-jX_{C2}}{R_2-jX_{C2}}$$

The equation for \$V_{R1}\$ is also found by voltage division but, to apply it, you must combine the impedances of R1, R2, and C2:

$$V_{R2}=V_{in}\frac{R_1||(R_2-jX_{C2})}{-jX_{C1} + R_1||(R_2-jX_{C2})}$$

Thus, the transfer function is:

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=  \frac{R_1||(R_2-jX_{C2})}{-jX_{C1} + R_1||(R_2-jX_{C2})}\frac{-jX_{C2}}{R_2-jX_{C2}}$$

the simplification of which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I am trying to simplify but I am getting weird forms

Comment: If I didn't make any typos while entering the formula in [mathomatic](http://mathomatic.org/) ... $$V_{out} = \dfrac{X_{C2}^2 R_1((j*X_{C2}) + R_2)}{(j((jX_{C2}) + R1)((R_2X_{C2}) - (X_{C1}((jXc2) + R_2)))(R_2 - jX_{C2}))}\cdot V_{in}$$ Better double check yourself ;o)

Comment: So, I have split up both the high pass filter and low pass filter and calculated both their gain.

Comment: @AceC1ub, the would be a fine approach if there were a buffer amplifier between the two sections but, in fact, the two sections interact.

Comment: See I am new to this but I was told that I can calculate the gain by solving the transfer function for both filters then multiplying them together.. Is that true?

Comment: @AceC1ub, no, that is not true.  It would only be true if the 1st section has zero output impedance or the 2nd section has infinite input impedance but neither is the case so, there is interaction.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Thanks but now I am completely confused. But I will try to understand this RC Bandpass Transfer Function if it kills me.

Comment: I used the equation jwRC/(1+jwRC) to calculate the gain for each filter but you say that is incorrect

Comment: @AceC1ub, I've already given you the transfer function as well as how to derive it.  All *you* need to do is plug in \$X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}\$ and use algebra to put it into standard form for a 1st order bandpass filter.

Comment: Yea you are right I was just confused on all these examples.

Answer (score 0):

Work out the voltage across the 15k resistor taking into account all the impedance of the components then, calculate the output voltage based purely on R2 and C2.

Or, use a simulation tool like LTSpice or, build it and use a signal generator and oscilloscope.